# N queen (algorithm) via array not understanding few lines

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, n-queens

http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/03-backtracking.pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GIXi.png)

**explain the highlighted texted of image**

Q[i]=j  Q[i]=j+r-i  Q[i]=j-r+i

how these statements check if two queen attack in row column or diagonals?

Comment: What to explain ? It's checking if: element at index i in Q array is equal to value that's held in j, OR if it's equal to j + r - 1 OR j - r + i, if any of those is true boolean variable legal gets set to false and the code below is not executed because legal is false.

Answer (score 0):

That's a better solution than I came up with many years ago when I beat the obvious algorithm by an order of magnitude.

Fundamentally, what this is doing is instead of maintaining a board and checking the three paths that a queen can move (you only need to look behind the queen--it's the only queen on the row so you know that direction is clear an the queens ahead haven't been placed yet) which requires checking (row - 1) * 3 cells (although some are off the board, it may be cheaper to test the diagonals for bounds first) it's maintaining a **one** dimensional array of queens and noting what they threaten.  This reduces each placement test to 3  squares.  (And uses only addition, no multiplication.  Irrelevant now, a considerable time savings when I was playing with this.)

I haven't looked over the whole thing to see how they are doing it with one array rather than the three I did it with (column threatened, / diagonal threatened, \ diagonal threatened.  The latter arrays are twice as big.)